# When any event triggers get the View object before the event handler function gets called

Tags: android

How to get the view object for which the the event is triggered before it actually goes to a handler method.
For ex: Lets say there are three buttons on a screen and whose onClick events are as follows.

```
1. btnSaveUser
2. btnUpdateUser
3. btnDeleteUser
```

The handler methods for the above are as follows.

```
public void btnSaveUser(View view) {
    .......
}

public void btnUpdateUser(View view) {
    ......
}

public void btnDeleteUser(View view) {
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you will get id of view, with this Id you can identify your button

```
public void btnDeleteUser(View view) {
    int id = view.getId()
}
```

Comment: Before the method **btnDeleteUser(View view)**  is being called i need the view object in fact i need the view object of any event before it actually goes to a handler method

Comment: In that case, you have to do - bDeleteUser = findViewById(R.id.bDeleteUser)

Comment: I do not want to hard code it like that for each event.Is there a general way, where i can get the view object before any handler method gets called for any view's event.